# Data from NodeJs (Express) API not reflecting on React Frontend for some users in some locations

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have a web app, which is a transportation system. I used ReactJs for the frontend and Express for the Backend/API. I hosted the server as a subdomain and the frontend in the public html folder (shared hosting on NameCheap).

At the frontend, it makes an api call when you search for a trip and then fetch the data from the database and stores it in React State at the frontend.

This works fine from my end and several other devices I have used. However, my client who is in another location doesn't seems to experience same thing. If he access the site and searches for a trip using same details that I used, it keeps on loading and does not update state with the result of the query, hence  it keeps on loading.

I am at a total loss as to why this is happening and why I can access it from my end and everything works fine, but from my client end, he accesses it but no data is loaded.

Note, we are in same country but different cities.

I don't know if anyone has experice something like this before using React and Node, and how it was resolved.

The website is https://croc-cityshuttle.com
Search Terms: Departure: Kaduna, Destination: Kafanchan, Date: 10/02/2022

Thanks.

I have tried using different browsers: Chrome, Firefox, Safari.
I tried different OS: Linux, Windows, MacOS, Android, iOS.

It works fine in all, but from my client's end, it doesn't.

===== Edit =======
Below is the code from React:

```
const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState({
trip_from: location.state.trip_from,
trip_to: location.state.trip_to,
trip_date: location.state.trip_date
});

const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)

useEffect(() =>
    {
        setLoading(true)
            axios.post("https://server.croc-cityshuttle.com/api/get-trips", searchTerm).then(res =>{
                setLoading(false)
                setSearchData(res.data);
            });

    },[]);
```

--- Here is the Express API ---

```
 routes.post("/get-trips", (req, res) =>{
    const {trip_from, trip_to, trip_date} = req.body;
    let sql = `SELECT v.vehicle_name as vehicle_name, v.vehicle_photo as vehicle_photo, v.front_seats, v.row1_seats, v.row2_seats, v.row3_seats, v.row4_seats,
    v.no_of_seats as trip_seats, t.trip_id as trip_id, t.trip_vehicle as vehicle_id, t.trip_fare as trip_fare, t.trip_date as trip_time,
    COUNT(tst.trip_id) as available_seats
    FROM trip_tbl t
    JOIN trip_seats_tbl tst ON tst.trip_id = t.trip_id
    JOIN vehicle_tbl v ON v.vehicle_id = t.trip_vehicle 
    WHERE t.trip_from =?  AND t.trip_to =? AND DATE(t.trip_date) =? AND t.trip_started !=1  AND tst.isbooked=0 AND t.trip_vehicle = tst.vehicle_id group by t.trip_id`
    con.query(sql,[trip_from, trip_to, trip_date], 
    (err, result) =>{
        if(err) res.json({success:false});
        else {
            if(result.length > 0) res.json(result)
            else res.json({notFound: true, success:true})
            
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: Please give a [mre].

Comment: I have edited the post with some codes

Comment: Perhaps you could add some error handling code on the axios request to get more insight on what's going wrong? See https://axios-http.com/docs/handling_errors

I recommend trying to figure out where the code is failing. Is the front-end request reaching the backend? Is the backend reaching the database?